# Jquery Mobile Scrollview list height bug

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I load the page, my scrollview works perfectly, but when I navigate away from the main page and I try to return to it, the scrollview forgets where the top of the scrollview ought to be.  It thinks that the place that I left the scrollview at before navigating away is the top of the list, and it thinks that the bottom of the list is somewhere beyond where the bottom actually is, thus it allows the user to scroll to far and then the scrollview disappears and cant be recovered unless i call scrollTo in the console.

I have tried doing scrollTo(0,0) on pagehide and beforepagehide with no luck -- the page will begin at the top when its shown, but it will immediately scroll down.

Here's how to reproduce the issue:

1) Go to http://7.latest.foodtrucksmap.appspot.com/m/la

2)  Scroll down the list and select the detail disclosure on one of the cells.

3)  Hit the 'Map' icon in the header to return to the original view.

At this point the scrollview will be in the state I've described.

Thanks a lot for the assistance in getting this resolved.

Comment: hmm tested the site on iPhone 4 running iOS 4.3.2 and it worked fine. Followed you instructions and the only problem I saw is the map goes to the original view point instead of the truck I had selected, but the truck I had selected in the list (which was towards the bottom) was still in view. It did start at the top when the page loaded but had scrolled to were I was after the initial loading. On a side note my friend runs http://socalmfva.com/ he might be interested in something like this

Comment: It sounds like you got to the page with the issue but didn't test for it.  Once you return to the map, try to scroll up.  What happens is that jqm makes the top of the list where you left off, the absolute top of the scrollview.  i havent met the socalmvfa people yet, but i know of the stuff that theyre working on and im sure hes heard of our app ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by calling `$('#list_content').scrollTop(0)` on pageshow